# Reactive API Call on tap button produces a leak

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactive

I know it's not the best use-case but let's say I have a button which calls an API Service every time is tapped. Something like this:

**ViewController**

```
myButton.tap.flatMap { [unowned self] _ in 
    return self.webService.apiCall()
}.suscribe(someObserver)
.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

**WebService**

```
class WebService {
    func apiCall() -> Observable<[Result]> {
        return RxAlamofire.requestData(.get, url).map { [unowned self] response, data -> [MyResult] in
             return self.parse(data)
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm using every tap to request some information. Now, every observable is unique and inmutable and every tap would generate a new Observable I'm subscribing to.

Am I wrong or doesn't it mean that I have a leak here and every requested observable (that is, every API call) isn't being disposed? What would it be an elegant way to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `flatMapLatest` which will only keep alive the subscription to the last inner sequence (`apiCall` in your case). This also means that very close `tap`s could terminate previous calls before they actually returned a result.

If you make `apiCall` return a `Single` or a sequence that emits a result and then completes, you would not accumulate subscriptions.

On a side note, it's not a leak. Your disposeBag has a reference to the sequence so if it were disposed, all memory would be freed resulting in no leak.
You only have to make sure the closure doesn't retain `self` but from your code I can't tell if `apiCall` belongs to self.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I tried to write a pseudo-code and forgot about the self. I've edited it and make it look like what I have